# Linking C with Assembly in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, masm

I'm trying to link main.c program with procedure.asm. I have the following C program and Assembly program.

main.c

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
extern "C" {
    void ClearUsingIndex(int[], int);    
}
static int Array[10] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1};

int main() 
{
    int size = 10;

    ClearUsingIndex( Array, size);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

procedure.asm

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 

    TITLE   c:\Users\GS\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ClearIndex\ClearIndex\procedure.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB MSVCRTD
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  ?ClearUsingIndex@@YAXQAHH@Z         ; ClearUsingIndex
EXTRN   __RTC_InitBase:PROC
EXTRN   __RTC_Shutdown:PROC
;   COMDAT rtc$TMZ
rtc$TMZ SEGMENT
__RTC_Shutdown.rtc$TMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_Shutdown
rtc$TMZ ENDS
;   COMDAT rtc$IMZ
rtc$IMZ SEGMENT
__RTC_InitBase.rtc$IMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_InitBase
rtc$IMZ ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Odtp /RTCsu /ZI
;   COMDAT ?ClearUsingIndex@@YAXQAHH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_i$ = -8                        ; size = 4
_Array$ = 8                     ; size = 4
_size$ = 12                     ; size = 4
?ClearUsingIndex@@YAXQAHH@Z PROC            ; ClearUsingIndex, COMDAT
; File c:\users\gs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\clearindex\clearindex\procedure.cpp
; Line 2
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 204                ; 000000ccH
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-204]
    mov ecx, 51                 ; 00000033H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
; Line 4
    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN3@ClearUsing
$LN2@ClearUsing:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], eax
$LN3@ClearUsing:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR _size$[ebp]
    jge SHORT $LN4@ClearUsing
; Line 5
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _Array$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+eax*4], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN2@ClearUsing
$LN4@ClearUsing:
; Line 6
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
?ClearUsingIndex@@YAXQAHH@Z ENDP            ; ClearUsingIndex
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

I did some research and I found the following source and followed the instructions: [Guide to Using Assembly in Visual Studio .NET](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/vsasm.html)

But I get the following error when I compile the assembly file.

```
error A1017: missing source filename
```

I google the error but all the methods I tried don't seem to work.

Comment: That guide is quite dated, which version of Visual Studio are yo using? I was able to get it working in VS 2013 Express after I removed the run-time checks from your ASM and corrected the name mangling. [Edit: hit enter on accident]. The error you're getting is because you probably incorrectly setup the MASM compiler from that guide. Newer Visual Studio's you just need to place the file in the project with .asm, and then go to properties and mark in included and to be built with "Microsoft Macro Assembler".

Comment: I'm using VS Express 2012. I did find another resource that suggested the same. I used it and it works. Thank you.

Comment: One issue you may run into is that you're using C++, not C.  You'll need to make sure you're using the correct name mangling for your ASM symbols, or declare them `extern "C"` in your C++ source code.