# MASM64, Visual studio 2015 C program with assembly function in separate file

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, x86-64, masm

[Linking C with Assembly in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739425/linking-c-with-assembly-in-visual-studio)
I've seen that already but that doesn't contain any helpful informations.

I have a C program, in which I'm using function written in assembly.
I include fun.h header in C file with declaration, and have fun.asm with implementation.
It was firstly written using NASM, and there is a `global` keyword. How can I achieve the same proper linking effect in MASM?

Minimal example:

main.c:

```
int main() 
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

f.h:

```
void f();
```

f.asm:

```
   .DATA
_05 DQ 0.5
_PI DQ 3.14159265358979323846264338327

   .CODE
public _f
_f PROC
_f ENDP
   END
```

Comment: `PUBLIC` keyword rather than  `GLOBAL`

Comment: When I use public, I've got unresolved external symbol error

Comment: Ah, probably because the Windows _C_ calling convention expects a leading underscore. So if you have a function called `myfun`, rename it `_myfun` and use `PUBLIC _myfun`

Comment: I've read about that already. In my asm file I have renamed it, in C files it is without underscores.

Comment: Have you enabled the custom build target for MASM within your project? By default if you add an `.asm` file through Visual Studio into a project it isn't automatically assembled (or linked). Riht mouse click the project name(not the solution name), click "Build Dependencies" in the menu, then select "Build Customizations" and then put a check box next to MASM

Comment: Yes, I added MASM in build customizations.

Comment: Okay can you present a minimal complete example (C code and an assembly file) in your question.

Comment: Oh when you created your prototype for your function in the header did you qualify the function with `extern "C"` linkage? Without it, MSVC++ will assume C++ name mangling which you don't want.

Comment: No because with code written in C, not C++ it gives syntax error.

Comment: Change `void f();` to `extern "C" void f();`

Comment: As I wrote, it doesn't work with C code.

Comment: I wrote it without seeing your last comment.

Comment: Actually with that directive, an asm file doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, I see you tagged this x86-64.

Comment: Error MSB3721 The command "ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Debug\f.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"PATH"\f.asm" exited with code 1. MASMSwirl C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 50      Code in asm file is as it is in example.

Comment: Since it is x86-64, no model directive is needed and you won't need the underscores on the PROC functions. I compiled it with those changes here and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what Michael Petch wrote in comment:
Searched keyword is PUBLIC, and in x86_64 there is NO need for underscore on PROC functions.